# Double multiplication takes 100 times longer if I use certain specific numbers

Tags: c#, math, filter, double

I have a simple function to implement an IIR filter:

```
public static double[] Process(FilterWeights fw, double[] points)
{
    int len = points.Length;
    double[] b = fw.b;
    double[] a = fw.a;
    double[] pout = new double[len];
    for (int i = 7; i < len - 7; i++)
    {
        double bb = b[0] * points[i] + b[1] * points[i - 1] + b[2] * points[i - 2] + b[3] * points[i - 3] + b[4] * points[i - 4] + b[5] * points[i - 5] + b[6] * points[i - 6];
        double aa = a[1] * pout[i - 1] + a[2] * pout[i - 2] + a[3] * pout[i - 3] + a[4] * pout[i - 4] + a[5] * pout[i - 5] + a[6] * pout[i - 6];

        pout[i] = bb - aa;
    }
    return pout;
}
```

When I use these weights:

```
double[] b = { 0.00127153313835457, 0, -0.0038145994150637, 0, 0.0038145994150637, 0, -0.00127153313835457 };
double[] a = { 1, -5.52631330458372, 12.7445836427234, -15.7022100579719, 10.9025543810024, -4.04524317719105, 0.626628537931204 };
```

The function executes in 0.1s

When I use these

```
double[] b = { 0.990561854840211 / divider, -5.94337112904127 / divider, 14.8584278226032 / divider, -19.8112370968042 / divider, 14.8584278226032 / divider, -5.94337112904127 / divider, 0.990561854840211 / divider };
double[] a = { 1, -5.98103409448638 / divider, 14.9053502415818 / divider, -19.8110589417825 / divider, 14.8114163250404 / divider, -5.90588631861786 / divider, 0.98121278826448 / divider };
```

It takes 10 seconds.

I did a performance analysis and indeed it is this line:

```
double aa = a[1] * pout[i - 1] + a[2] * pout[i - 2] + a[3] * pout[i - 3] + a[4] * pout[i - 4] + a[5] * pout[i - 5] + a[6] * pout[i - 6];
```

That takes way longer in the second case.

I am completely baffled. I tried truncating the numbers, dividing them by 1000 and other methods, but it looks like there is something in the number themselves that increases computation by 10x!

The first weights are for a 0.5-10hz band pass butterworth filter with order 3. The second set of weights is for a 0.2hz high pass filter with order 6. It sort of makes sense that a higher order filter would take longer, but I can't explain how double multiplication is affected by the actual numbers, that is even when ALL weights are divided by a large factor.

Comment: PS: The variable "divider" is set to 1 but its magnitude does not seem to affect computation time

Comment: Lots of zeros in your first set of weights.  Maybe the CPU knows enough to treat those specially.  (But then I'd expect the bb line, not the aa line, to be the one that shows the performance difference.)

Comment: For these kind of questions, specify which Framework (version), Compiler (VS) version, Release/Debug mode, how you tested etc.

Comment: Is `divider` a *variable* or a *constant*?

Comment: No repro. Post a [mcve] when you can make this stick. Again, tell us about versions, configurations etc.

Comment: There exists situation when magnitude does affect computation time - denormalized numbers, but we don't know whether such case might happen for you.

Comment: Hi - the "b" weights seem not to matter. The time is taken in the "a" weights computation. The difference in execution time is 0.7% for the b weights against 66.5% for the a weights! Using .net 4.5, VS2015, and release mode. I use the performance profiler (but it is not needed since the 10s execution time is clearly noticeable when watching the program progress). Finally divider is a variable, but it doesn't matter, weights are only computed once, also it doesn't matter if I remove "divider" from the weight definition.

Comment: as stated above, we don't have a sample input, however, I generated a random input of about 1000000 numbers using only positive numbers between 0 and 22000 given you mentioned hz. Running the second set of filters, `aa` quickly becomes `NaN` for all numbers past a certain point (around the 600th number), where it doesn't for the first set, but it's impossible to tell if these are within the range of inputs you expect to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joshua Webb.
Indeed the input array had NaNs, which caused bb to become NaN conditionally at one iteration. Once this happened, all subsequent aa calculations also involved and resulted in NaNs which seems to take a lot longer than a normal multiplication between non-NaN numbers.
After removing all NaNs from the input array, the problem seems to have been resolved :D